# How to handle cloudfront cache after deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

we have our Angular2 code in S3 .And we access it via Cloudfront.
It works fine.
But after a deployment to Angular2 , we want every code to be invalidated from Cloudfront.
What are the best approaches for clearing cache after deployment?
How to handle cloudfront caching?

Answer (score 12):

You can do both deployment and cache invalidation with the help of aws-cli.

```
#!/bin/bash

# enable cloudfront cli
aws configure set preview.cloudfront true

# deploy angular bundles
aws s3 sync $LOCAL s3://$S3_BUCKET \
    --region=eu-central-1 \
    --cache-control max-age=$CACHE_TIME

# invalidate cache in cloudfront
aws cloudfront create-invalidation \
    --distribution-id $CLOUDFRONT_DISTRO_ID \
    --paths "/*"
```

Answer (score 6):

You will need to call the CloudFront API (or use the web console) to invalidate the cache. [Here is the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that one problem with these solutions (as I have found out the hard way) is that the CloudFront Invalidation will probably run before the CodeDeploy has finished deploying to all EC2 instances.

Some factors are your Deployment Config, and how many EC2 instances you have.  I'm thinking of adding some checks to this kind of process that gets the deployment status and will invalidate after a success

Comment: I've realized that the best way for me to handle this is to have a Lambda function that is triggered by a SNS event.  The SNS event is called by CodeDeploy on Deployment Success only.  So, I'll only invalidate the cache on a successful deployment.

Comment: There is no mentioning of servers in the questions. App is server from S3 over CloudFront, there is no EC2.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that.  Post is 3 years old and has no up or down votes.  But Thanks.